# Adding text above and under nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, tikz-node

I have following figure

```
\documentclass[border=0.9cm]{standalone}
 
% More defined colors
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
% Required package
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\definecolor{gr}{RGB}{221, 220, 221}
 
\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw=gr,
    fill=gr,
    rounded corners,
    minimum width=3cm,
    minimum height=1.2cm,
]  (controller) {$equations$};
 
\node [draw=gr,
    fill=gr, 
    rounded corners,
    minimum width=2cm, 
    minimum height=1.2cm, 
    below right= 1cm and -4cm of controller
]  (sensor) {\begin{tabular}{c} Dynamical \\ system \end{tabular}};
        
\draw[-stealth] (controller.east) -- +(0.6,0) |- node[pos=0.755, above]{$\text{control input}$} (sensor.east);
\draw[-stealth] (sensor.west) -- +(-1.8,0) |- node[pos=0.5,left]{$x(k)$} (controller.west);
    
\end{tikzpicture}
 
\end{document}
```

How can I add text like here (marked with red)

[image]

Comment: Insert another `node[pos=0.5,left]{Text}` simply changing the position value and the alignment  (for example, above, below, right, left).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
\draw[-stealth] (controller.east) -- +(0.6,0) |- node[pos=0.755, above]{control input} node[pos=0.755, below]{another text here}  (sensor.east);
\draw[-stealth] (sensor.west) -- node[above]{Text also here} +(-1.8,0) |- node[pos=0.5,left]{$x(k)$} (controller.west);
```

You can have several `node` commands one after the other.

BTW, you can replace `$\text{some words}$` by `some words`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\definecolor{gr}{RGB}{221, 220, 221}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw=gr,
    fill=gr,
    rounded corners,
    minimum width=3cm,
    minimum height=1.2cm,
]  (controller) {$equations$};
 
\node [draw=gr,
    fill=gr, 
    rounded corners,
    minimum width=2cm, 
    minimum height=1.2cm, 
    below right= 1cm and -4cm of controller,
    align=center
]  (sensor) {Dynamical \\ system};
        
\draw[-stealth]
  (controller.east)
  -- +(0.6,0) node[pos=0.5,above]{X}
  |- node[pos=0.755, above]{control input}
     node[pos=0.755, below]{another text}
  (sensor.east);
\draw[-stealth]
  (sensor.west)
  -- node[above]{also here} +(-1.8,0)
  |- node[pos=0.5,left]{$x(k)$}
  (controller.west);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ok, thanks, i tried something similar, but didn't work

Comment: hello, do you have any idea how to add text on the line after block equation? @gernot

Comment: @elsa I have extended my answer.